# transfer opentype to paper.js, bézier curve problem

Tags: javascript, paperjs, opentype

I am trying to transfer a font from opentype to a paper.js path object. I am using opentype.js to get the points out of the letter and than i try to make a new paper path out of this points.

Sounds simple, but somehow i can not work out this curves. I am trying to find how this is done with the examples and the reference of paper.js. but i can not find it.

from opentype.js i get paths like this:

```
{type: "C", x: 56.3, x1: 58.4, x2: 56.3, y: 111.9, y1: 90, y2: 97.80000000000001}
```

(here x/y is the basic point and the x1/y1 and x2/y2 are its related point handlers.)

and now i tried to put this into a paper.js path:

```
var segments = [];

    segments.push(new Segment(
        new Point(119,111.30000000000001)
        ));
    segments.push(new Segment(
        new Point(119,284.1)
        ));
    segments.push(new Segment(
        new Point(139.7,302.7),
        new Point(119,300),
        new Point(125.89999999999999,302.7)
        ));
    segments.push(new Segment(
        new Point(161,284.1),
        new Point(150.2,302.7),
        new Point(161,300.3)
        ));

        var path = new Path(segments);
        path.strokeColor = "black"
```

All the non curved paths are correct. but the handlers are shown with no logic position...

anyone any ideas?

Comment: The path is [documented well enough](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/blob/master/README.md#path-commands) and the one you're showing is a `curveTo` instruction, from "wherever we are" to "x/y", over two control points x1/y1 and x2/y2. Given that, I have no idea what you're trying to show with the other snippet of code: it's not showing how you're trying to draw this at all, it's just showing hardcoded values that clearly don't come from a font?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your answer. Yes i know the above is not a letter it's just a sample of how i tried to make the path. So i uploaded my sketch here (https://kajetansom.ch/opentype/) for better understanding. In the example i only draw with paper.js, i only used opentype.js to get the points from the font. The halder points seem to be correct. (I marked them with the circles and the lines in red and blue). But if i try to use this handles in paper.js it does not use them correctly as you can see on the blue handlers. Hope this describes my problem bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Segment.handleIn`](http://paperjs.org/reference/segment/#handlein) and `Segment.handleOut` are coordinates relative to the anchor point. Make sure you give relative coordinates for handles, not absolute.

An easy solution would be to use OpenType.js to convert your font to SVG width [`Path.toSVG(decimalPlaces)`](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js/blob/master/README.md), then import it in paper.js with [`importSVG(svg[, options])`](http://paperjs.org/reference/project/#importsvg-svg).

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect with the SVG workaround :) 
Just for clarification i wonder how i could get the relative coordinates of the handles out of the absolute ones. is there a way?

Comment: of course, to get relative coordinates, just subtract the absolute ones (the absolute position of the handle point) to the anchor point position. This will give you a vector going from the anchor point to the handle point.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out! :)